# What is the proper statistical way to meausre the confidence of a probability distribution?

Tags: distributions

I have a 3-class probability distribution produced by a classification model. For example:

$$y = [0.1, 0.7, 0.2]$$

I want to plot a simple measure of confidence for a set of predictions.

What I've done is treat $y$ as a vector and take its magnitude. Chance is the lowest confidence with a magnitude of:

$$|y_{min}| = |[0.33, 0.33, 0.33]| = 0.576773$$

A 100% confident assignment has a magnitude of 1:

$$|y_{max}| = |[1, 0, 0]| = 1.0$$

Then I simply rescale $y$ to a $[0, 1]$ range to produce the confidence

$$\text{confidence}(y) = \frac{|y| - |y_{min}|}{|y_{max}|-|y_{min}|}$$

My questions:

- Is there anything problematic with that measure of confidence?
- Is there another method that is more applicable to this case?

Comment: Would variance work?

Comment: Good idea, variance can work in the same way. It produces a different scale of the confidence. Is there a reason why one method vs. another would be preferred?

Comment: People are familiar with variance.

Comment: The variance of *what*?  We have probabilities, but no values - there is no variance to compute here.

Comment: Entropy is likely to be what your looking for. Low entropy (zero) corresponds to your confidence = 1 case. The uniform case will have the highest entropy.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to get at the notion of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)).

Comment: +1 I was going to say the same thing. You could improve this answer a lot by expanding it.

Comment: What could I add that isn't in the linked wikipedia article?

Comment: That's not entirely the point. A good stack exchange answer should always provide an answer to the question without a reader *needing* to check out any links. With that said, links are encouraged for readers who want more details.